# Kotlin Quick sort algorithm does not do any sorting and returns the original array

Tags: sorting, kotlin, quicksort

i have this simple quick sort algorithm written in kotlin. It returns the original array without any sorting done. Can anyone point out any errors in my code? it would be appreciated.

```
class QuickSort {

  fun sort(low: Int, high: Int, array: Array<Int>) {
    if (low < high) {
      val partitionIndex = partition(low, high, array)
      sort(low, partitionIndex - 1, array)
      sort(partitionIndex + 1, high, array)
    }
  }

  private fun partition(low: Int, high: Int, array: Array<Int>): Int {
    var leftPointer = low - 1
    val pivot = array[high]
    for (i in low until high) {
      if (array[i] <= pivot) {
        leftPointer++
        swap(array, i, leftPointer)
      }
    }
    swap(array, leftPointer + 1, high)
    return leftPointer + 1
  }

  private fun swap(array: Array<Int>, firstIndex: Int, secondIndex: Int) {
    val temp = array[firstIndex]
    array[firstIndex] = array[secondIndex]
    array[secondIndex] = temp
  }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  val quickSort = QuickSort()
  val array = mutableListOf(9, 8, 7, 6, 5)
  //Should return 5,6,7,8,9
  quickSort.sort(0, array.size - 1, array.toTypedArray())
  for (i in 0 until array.size) {
    println(array[i])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined `array` field as a mutable list, and passing `array.toTypedArray()` to the `sort` function. `array.toTypedArray()` would be a different object reference altogether that gets sorted, and `array` object remains as is.

To fix, just define the variable properly using `arrayOf` function and send the same variable to the `sort` function

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  val quickSort = QuickSort()
  val array = arrayOf(9, 8, 7, 6, 5)
  quickSort.sort(0, array.size - 1, array)
  for (element in array) {
    println(element)
  }
}
```